# show only .classpath files in eclipse package view?

Tags: eclipse, filter

Normally eclipse filters are used to hide .* files like .classpath files. But is the inverse possible, to show only .classpath files in eg. the package view and hide all other elements, folders, files etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it would require writing a plug-in that contributes that kind of filter.